# Accessing files on a Windows 7 Professional laptop from a Windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking

I recently purchased a refurbished laptop running Windows 7 Professional. I also own a desktop running Windows 8.1. I want to have access to all the files on the Windows 7 Professional laptop—less the system files—from my Windows 8.1desktop.

After many a tries and reading several articles I can’t seem to get this task completed. It seems that the “Home Group” concept only allows you to share files in a public folder. Is there any way around this?
I don’t see any options under “Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center ->” in either Windows 8 or Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share any folder on the W7 machine by right-clicking on the folder you want to share, choose Properties and then the sharing tab. If that tab isn't present, it is likely that it was blocked by the previous owners Group Policy settings. You may be able to get round that if you can create a new user it with local administrator rights.

The easiest way to connect to the W7 machine is via its IP address, type:

```
\\192.168.1.50\sharename
```

or whatever it's address is into the address bar in Windows Explorer.

It should throw up a prompt for a user id & password. Don't forget that the userid needs to be one on the W7 PC not on the W8 PC and that it is worth prefixing the user id with a `\` to ensure that it doesn't try to look up the id in the local machines workgroup.

UPDATE:

On the W7 laptop you should have a default user login, that is the one you need to put into the popup on the W8 laptop. For example, if your W7 login id is called `user`, create the share on the W7 laptop while logged in with `user`. Then on the W8 laptop, try to access the share as indicated above. When you get the credential request put `\user` (note the leading backslash) into the ID field and enter the password.

Comment: Using my version of your suggestion in Windows Explorer: "\\192.168.1.5\c"  I receive an error message.  You do not have permission to access.... Contact your network administrator to request access.  I have setup file and printer sharing on both machines.  My printer is attached to the Win8 desktop and I cannot attach the printer from my laptop.  I tried looking at the Firewall on both systems but I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: Are you getting a pop-up asking for credentials? If not, try a reboot first then try again. If still not, the account is configured to automatically pass the incorrect credentials. In that case, it may be best to reset Windows back to default settings. This will loose any installed software but retain any data.

Comment: I re-installed Windows and now I get the popup asking for my credentials but I don't know where to set them on the Laptop.  Also on the laptop although I can access the shared public folder from both machine I am not able to complete the process of joining a Home Group on the laptop.  After I place the Home Group password in, it churns and churns but never completes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I don’t know why it works.
I deleted the Home Group on my desktop. I went to this directory:
“windows\serviceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking”
and deleted all the files on both desktop and laptop.
I then went back to my laptop and created a new Home Group and then moved to the laptop and joined the group and it meraciously worked and joined my desktop priter to the group.
Thanks all for help.